# Comparing paths between two different machine

Tags: python, shell, perl

I have a file which contains a list of paths that were used on machine `A`. I would like to check each path on machine `B`. At this point, I just iterate through the list on machine `B` and check the existence of the path (by using `-e` flag in Perl). Problem is I have paths on machine `A` that does not exactly exists on machine `B`, rather they exist but with a different path. For example:

```
machine A: /usr/bin/pkgs/python/2.7.2/lib/site-packages/_ssl.so
machine B: /usr/bin/pkgs/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/pkgs/_ssl.so
```

Some tool (let's call it `toolX`) on machine `A` uses the first path and on machine `B` the second one. Is it possible to find a way in order to alert if the file does not exist at all on machine `B`? For starters, I would like to start with `Perl` and `Python` packages and modules. I have a list of versions of `Perl` and `Python` that works on machine `B` and I would like to alert if some module does not exist. Maybe I should iterate over the `Perl` and `Python` packages (with `find`) and look for all similar modules with the same name and maybe the same size.

Part of my code for now:

```
open(my $fh_d, '>', $destination) or return 0;
open(my $fh_s, '<', $source) or return 0;

while(my $file = <$fh_s>) {
    chomp($file);
    print $fh_d $file."\n" unless(-e $file);
}

close ($fh_s);
close ($fh_d);
```

In summary, I would like to alert if a specific path does not exist on machine `B` but in a smart way, so if there is another path with the same name, it might be it (the question is how?). What is the best way to approach this issue? How should I check if the path is `perl` or `python` path for sure?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what this *same-ness* means?   Just the filename? In your example, `2.7.2` `_ssl.so` is really not the same (probably) as the one from `2.7.5`.  But it does have the same name.  Maybe if the names are the same, the code could calculate a checksum of the file or suchlike to determine if they really are identical.  Then "find" the match with the last amount of path letter-differences.

Comment: I see you went back to "source" and "destination", but those names make no sense since you're not copying. Orig/old and new make more sense.

Comment: Also... `return 0` on error? What's up with that???

Comment: Do you want the tool to iterate `file.txt` (list of filenames) and if a file does not exist on B, it should use some heuristic approach to check if a "similar" file could exists instead? (If so, then *"similar"* should first be more closely defined I think)

Comment: As far as I understand, you have a list of directories on A where for each dir you want to output true or false on whether the dir exists on machine B.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you have a list of directories on A where for each dir you want to output true or false on whether the dir exists on machine B

```
find /etc/ -type d > /tmp/dirlist
cat /tmp/dirlist | ssh B "perl -nle'print q().(-d\$_?q(yes):q(no)).qq( \$_)'"
```

...where B is your other machine. Replace `B` with `username@remote.server.org` or something. Remember ssh can invoke any command on the remote server which get the same stdin and stdout. The default is the users shell (for instance bash). The `q(string)` and `qq()` quotation methods are just to avoid using `'` and `"` since I have used up those already.